# Azure Active Directory B2B Pending and Accepted User Reports

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I have a requirement in which I need to get a list of Azure AD B2B users who haven't accepted the invitation using csom or rest api

Can you please let me know whether graph provides any such endpoints?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, we can [use Microsoft Graph User API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) to implement it. The user's property `externalUserState` represents the invited user's invitation status. For invited users, the state can be PendingAcceptance or Accepted, or null for all other users. But please note that if you want to use Microsoft Graph User API to get the property, we need to `beta` version
[image]
For example

1. Get all users  externalUserState

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=externalUserState,displayName,id
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

[image]

2. Get all users  who haven't accepted the invitation

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=externalUserState,displayName,id&$filter=externalUserState eq 'PendingAcceptance'
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim. It is helpful. But, the V1.0 of Microsoft Graph API does not provide these properties. I am not sure whether I can rely on this beta version as they can make changes at anytime.

Comment: @sj' According to the situation, you can try to use the AAD graph API `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$select=displayName,userState,userType&$filter= userType eq 'Guest'$api-version=1.6`:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy9lA.png

Comment: Thanks Jim. This is really helpful. I will try this from my end.

Comment: @sj' If it is useful for you, could you please accept it as an answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks Jim. It really helped me to resolve the issue.I had to make a small change to the endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/users"